# Photo editing app with Instagram like filters for Android

Tags: android, photography

I basically want Instagram filters on Android, without Instagram cropping my pictures.

Essentially it needs the following effects:

- Brightness
- Contrast
- Saturation
- Highlights/lowlights
- Structure

And other cool effects like tilt shift are good.

Beyond actually having effects, it needs to be *simple to use*, and have good feedback - (ie image changes smoothly has you slide the marker).

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Not everybody knows Instagram in detail but might know the app you're looking for. // You can also check with my [list of photo editor apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit) ;)